# Как сделать поле ввода во всю web-страницу?

Tags: веб-программирование

Я разрабатываю web-приложение Заметки, и когда пользователь нажимает создать заметку у него должна выскакивать пустая страница для ввода своей заметки, но я не знаю, как мне сделать такую страницу ввода. В идеале он может вставлять туда еще и картинки. Чтобы реализовать текстовый вариант я пробовал тег textarea, но получается какой-то костыль. Подкиньте, пожалуйста, инфы на эту тему, а то в интернете пусто.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="
    height: 100%;
    border: solid;
"> Hello World!</div>
```